# Remove javascript prototype using sed in cygwin

Tags: javascript, regex, sed, cygwin

How would I go about and remove the listInfo prototype and logInfo object from the code bellow.

My problem is with the listInfo prototype where I can't seem to find a way to remove the closing bracket. Everything else is easy to find and remove.

```
var ePlug = (function (undefined) {
    var logInfo, logErrors, logWarnings, hasError, version;

    function ePlug(options) {
        this.version = "0.1 Alpha";
        this.logInfo = [];
        this.logErrors = [];
        this.logWarnings = [];

        this.logInfo.push('Setting options start.');
        options = options || {};

        this.validate(options.one, 'string', 'one provided is not valid.');
        this.validate(options.two, 'boolean', 'two provided is not valid.');

        if(this.hasError !== true) {
            options.one = typeof options.one === 'string' ? options.one : 'string';
            options.two = typeof options.two === 'boolean' ? options.two : true;

            this.logInfo.push('Setting options end.');
            this.options = options;
        }
        else {
            this.logErrors.push('Setting options error.');
        }
    }

    ePlug.prototype.listInfo = function () {
        return this.logg(this.logInfo);
    };

    ePlug.prototype.listErrors = function () {
        return this.logg(this.logErrors);
    };

    ePlug.prototype.listWarnings = function () {
        return this.logg(this.logWarnings);
    };

    ePlug.prototype.logg = function (what) {
        if(typeof window.console === 'undefined') {
           alert(what);
        }
        else {
           console.log(what);
        }
    };

    ePlug.prototype.init = function () {
        if(this.hasError !== true) {
            // start here
        }
    };

    return ePlug;
})();

var eOpt = (function () {
    function options() { return {}; }
    return options;
})();

eOpt.one = 'test';
eOpt.two = false;
var ePlug = new ePlug(eOpt);
ePlug.init();
```

I want to be able to remove the code bellow

```
ePlug.prototype.listInfo = function () {
    return this.logg(this.logInfo);
};
```

So far I can only remove the first two lines.

I have no idea how to go about removing the last line `};`

Comment: I've no idea what you want to remove. Also what have you tried ?

Comment: I have appended more info to the question. I have no tried anything as I can't find any documentation regarding how to delete a line by referencing to what was in the line before it. Considering that line was already removed.

Comment: That might be very difficult (if not impossible) if you want to take in account nested brackets ...

Comment: I managed to clean out everything except that bit. Is there another utility in cygwin that might do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed '/ePlug.prototype.listInfo = function () {/, /};/d' file
```

---

```
$cat file
var ePlug = (function (undefined) {
    var logInfo, logErrors, logWarnings, hasError, version;

    function ePlug(options) {
        this.version = "0.1 Alpha";
        this.logInfo = [];
        this.logErrors = [];
        this.logWarnings = [];

        this.logInfo.push('Setting options start.');
        options = options || {};

        this.validate(options.one, 'string', 'one provided is not valid.');
        this.validate(options.two, 'boolean', 'two provided is not valid.');

        if(this.hasError !== true) {
            options.one = typeof options.one === 'string' ? options.one : 'string';
            options.two = typeof options.two === 'boolean' ? options.two : true;

            this.logInfo.push('Setting options end.');
            this.options = options;
        }
        else {
            this.logErrors.push('Setting options error.');
        }
    }

    ePlug.prototype.listInfo = function () {
        return this.logg(this.logInfo);
    };

    ePlug.prototype.listErrors = function () {
        return this.logg(this.logErrors);
    };

    ePlug.prototype.listWarnings = function () {
        return this.logg(this.logWarnings);
    };

    ePlug.prototype.logg = function (what) {
        if(typeof window.console === 'undefined') {
           alert(what);
        }
        else {
           console.log(what);
        }
    };

    ePlug.prototype.init = function () {
        if(this.hasError !== true) {
            // start here
        }
    };

    return ePlug;
})();

var eOpt = (function () {
    function options() { return {}; }
    return options;
})();

eOpt.one = 'test';
eOpt.two = false;
var ePlug = new ePlug(eOpt);
ePlug.init();

$sed '/ePlug.prototype.listInfo = function () {/, /};/d' file
var ePlug = (function (undefined) {
    var logInfo, logErrors, logWarnings, hasError, version;

    function ePlug(options) {
        this.version = "0.1 Alpha";
        this.logInfo = [];
        this.logErrors = [];
        this.logWarnings = [];

        this.logInfo.push('Setting options start.');
        options = options || {};

        this.validate(options.one, 'string', 'one provided is not valid.');
        this.validate(options.two, 'boolean', 'two provided is not valid.');

        if(this.hasError !== true) {
            options.one = typeof options.one === 'string' ? options.one : 'string';
            options.two = typeof options.two === 'boolean' ? options.two : true;

            this.logInfo.push('Setting options end.');
            this.options = options;
        }
        else {
            this.logErrors.push('Setting options error.');
        }
    }


    ePlug.prototype.listErrors = function () {
        return this.logg(this.logErrors);
    };

    ePlug.prototype.listWarnings = function () {
        return this.logg(this.logWarnings);
    };

    ePlug.prototype.logg = function (what) {
        if(typeof window.console === 'undefined') {
           alert(what);
        }
        else {
           console.log(what);
        }
    };

    ePlug.prototype.init = function () {
        if(this.hasError !== true) {
            // start here
        }
    };

    return ePlug;
})();

var eOpt = (function () {
    function options() { return {}; }
    return options;
})();

eOpt.one = 'test';
eOpt.two = false;
var ePlug = new ePlug(eOpt);
ePlug.init();
```

Curly brackets `{}` are not special characters in BRE.